# Why was the tile on the end of a shower wall jogged over partway up?

Tags: bathtub, remodeling

Is it normal to not finish the wall and let the tiles that way with back liner ?

I don’t understand why would my contractor would not finish the wall here while so close to.

Yes it’s aligned to the other side of the bath tub (parallel or symmetric) but why not just finish the wall?

[image]

---

Thank you all for your thoughts on this,

Yes another thing is we agreed to tile the bath area to the ceiling and the rest of the bath from floor to the windows height

We will add glass doors

Tile guy told me it won’t be nice if tiles finished at the corner edge

Comment: What. The. Fork.  OP, are you the homeowner?

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Answer (score 9):

You said it yourself in the question - it's because it's aligned to the other side of the tub. If the tiled wall was continued all the way to the corner, there's a chance the finished product would look unbalanced, since the tub enclosure would extend further on one side than the other outside the glass/shower curtain. The way it's done now continues the wainscoating around the rest of the bathroom and keeps both sides of the enclosure balanced. This is likely the reasoning behind the design choice, whether it's the correct one is up to you.

Answer (score 7):

Because the entire bathroom has a wainscot on the lower portion and that's where the shower ends.

Look at the wall across the room. It has tile partway up and paint above. That's the design of the room. Then tile was placed on the shower walls. The shower walls end at some point, and apparently it was decided that they end short of the stub wall's face. This seems reasonable to me, assuming a glass shower or curtain rod will be installed appropriately. Tile and fiberglass panels often terminate in a similar manner.

A person could have run the tile to the corner, but that costs more and may not be the desired style.

[image]

[image]

[image]